# Why aren't the flex items not adjusting according to the screen size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <header>List of top 5 Netflix movies</header>
      {Mdata.filter((val) => val.title.indexOf(fave) !== -1).map((val) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={val.id}
            imgsrc={val.imgsrc}
            mtitle={val.title}
            mname={val.name}
            mlink={val.link}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <div className="card">
        <Image imgsrc={props.imgsrc} />
        <div className="card_info">
          <span>{props.mtitle}</span>
          <h4>{props.mname}</h4>
          <a href={props.mlink} target="_blank">
            <button type="submit">WATCH NOW</button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
header {
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
  font-family: "Shadows Into Light", cursive;
  color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.918);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: xx-large;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.cards {
  padding: 12rem 5rem 0 10rem;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 37rem;
  background-color: beige;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  margin: 0 5rem 5rem 0;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0, 1);
}
```

So under the screen size of 320px, it's not working properly, the cards aren't adjusting accordingly and also since they aren't shrinking maintaining the gap between them, they're going beyond the header which shouldn't be the case because header's taking the 100% width.

Comment: Can you provide the raw HTML?

Comment: You can maybe use responsive property for different screen size

Answer (score 0):

There are only less than 3% of mobile users who uses 320px when you doa research. And under that 320px is prob very small percentage to this date.
But if you need to adjust your code you need to use
@media only screen and (max-width:320px)
{  heres your css call for it}

```css
<!--put this on your css YOU HAVE TO EDIT THE BELOW CSS TO ADJUST IT AT 320px and look at it-->

@media only screen and (max-width:320px){

.cards {
  padding: 12rem 5rem 0 10rem;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 37rem;
  background-color: beige;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  margin: 0 5rem 5rem 0;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0, 1);
}

}
```

Comment: I needed the css actually

Comment: I dont have all your entire code to see it on media query of 320px you have to adjust your code. Ill edit the answer where you can edit your css.

Comment: @TanishaSethi I edited above answer you have to edit those css and see it to yourself because I dont have your entire code. Hope that helps